# IP over File System - how to make connection over file server with node.js

Tags: node.js, http, proxy

In a restricted environment (including port 80 is prohibited), I want to serve my local http server to another client. Both users are in a Domain and local admins. Only free common point for both computers is a file server.
There is;
    In server side: an http server serving on port 7001
    In client side: any browser to connect to server:7001

To make HTTP connection between client and server;
*Client side node.js application - like a proxy server*

  1. listens on
  **127.0.0.1:7001**

  2. directly writes
  **"requests from browser"**
  to a
  **"file on file server"**
  .

  3. and reads
  **"response from server"**
  on
  **"file on file server"**
  and directs to client browser.

*Server side node.js application - like a proxy server*

  1. listens to a
  **"request"**
  on
  **"file on file server"**

  2. redirects
  **"request"**
  to
  **"local_web_server:7001"**

  3. writes "response from server" on "file on file server"

If not clear, take a look at [IP_over_Avian_Carriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers)

Any guidance is appreciated. No intention to make people write all the code.
Thanks.

Note:
I'm using this node.js proxy server for another purpose.
https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2012/11/05/node-js-http-and-https-proxy/ 
It might help but I can not figure it out.

Comment: In your case, birds are file servers, flash memory devices are files on the servers, right? If so, you need to fly. Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: That's right. I'm a domain user and local administrator. Let me add this info on problem description.

Comment: Are you asking for the implementation of a complete system? Not going to happen. StackOverflow is not the place where you can post a bunch of requirements and then people do your job for you. Ask a concrete question that refers to a single problem you have with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a placeholder answer. My partner recently bought a transcend WiFi card for her dslr, and I thought it was just so cool that I bought myself one. Seeing as the card contains a 32 bit arm running linux and WiFi chipset in addition to the ordinary flash, I figure I can write some custom software that can read files off the disk, transmit them as IP packets, and write any received packets. From that point I can trivially give WiFi connectivity to any device with sd card support. A raspberry pi, arduino, etc. Watch this space for an implementation of the concept outlined in this question.

Comment: This is neither asking another question, nor asking for clarification from the author. It's stating that I'm going to be writing an implementation of what the author wants, and it will be available soon.